# c++ std::sort is working wrong

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to sort this below according to `xValue`:

```
Item
side: L
xValue:2
label: 0
yValue: 50

Item
side: R
xValue:10
label: 0
yValue: 50

Item
side: L
xValue:35
label: 1
yValue: 20

Item
side: R
xValue:55
label: 1
yValue: 20

Item
side: L
xValue:30
label: 2
yValue: 60

Item
side: R
xValue:45
label: 2
yValue: 60
```

In `Item.cpp`, I overloaded the operator `<`:

```
bool Item::operator < (const Item& itm) const{
    return (xValue < itm.xValue);
}
```

This is how I use `std::sort`:

```
sort(mainList.begin(), mainList.end());
```

But the result is:

```
Item
side: L
xValue:2
label: 0
yValue: 50

Item
side: L
xValue:35
label: 1
yValue: 20

Item
side: R
xValue:10
label: 0
yValue: 50

Item
side: R
xValue:55
label: 1
yValue: 20

Item
side: L
xValue:30
label: 2
yValue: 60

Item
side: R
xValue:45
label: 2
yValue: 60
```

What is wrong here?

**EDIT:** mainList:

```
vector<Item*> mainList;
```

mainList inserting:

```
if (myfile.is_open()){
    // read building count
    getline(myfile,line);
    buildingCount = atoi(split(line)[0].c_str());

    // read buildings
    for (int b=0; b < buildingCount; b++){
        getline(myfile,line);
        mainList.push_back(new Item('L', atoi(split(line)[0].c_str()), b, atoi(split(line)[1].c_str())));
        mainList.push_back(new Item('R', atoi(split(line)[2].c_str()), b, atoi(split(line)[1].c_str())));
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you without http://sscce.org/.

Comment: You need to at least tell us what mainList is. My guess is that it is a collection of pointers, and your code is now sorting them by pointer location. But it is just a guess.

Comment: Your `operator<` is only invoked when you compare two `Item`s. However you are comparing two `Item *` instead.

Comment: @M.M, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a functor for comparison and give it to sort as the third parameter:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/59164/

```
struct Compare {
    bool operator() (const Item* left, const Item* right) const { 
       return left->xValue < right->xValue;
    }
}

sort(mainList.begin(), mainList.end(), Compare());
```

Comment: Why is the overloading of operator < not working? What I gain by using this?

Comment: Now, it says this: `passing ‘const Item’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Item::getXValue()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Ok, its done. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::sort` function sorts correctly, but it only does what you tell it to do.

It sorts the elements in `mainList`. The 2 most common mistakes are:

1. You sort `mainList`, but print a different copy of `mainList`.
2. You sort based on another criteria than you intended. This will happen if `mainList` isn't a container of `Item` but instead a different type, like  `Item*` or `std::shared_ptr<Item>`.

These are just guesses, but without a complete example of  your problem we cannot do more than provide very general answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I used any built in sorting but I think your comparator may be different than you intend.

Try telling sort to use the greater than

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );



// sort using a standard library compare function object
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort